# cron.hourly script executing multiple times

Tags: bash, cron

## The setup

I have a script `/etc/cron.hourly/msm-hourly` that contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGPATH='/opt/msm/servers/cronscripts'
LOGFILE="$LOGPATH/msm-start.log"

# Make restart dead servers
echo "" >> $LOGFILE && /bin/date >> $LOGFILE && /etc/init.d/msm start >> $LOGFILE
```

Every hour:

1. Create a new line in the log file
2. Add the date
3. Then the output of the `msm start` command

**It works** running from the command line *as well as* within `/etc/cron.daily/`

## The issue

The output, when run from the command line looks like this:

```
[ msm-hourly.log ]

Thu Sep 12 20:56:51 UTC 2013
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
```

However, after leaving it run for a while the output on each iteration looks like this:

```
[ msm-hourly.log ]

Thu Sep 12 20:56:51 UTC 2013
[ACTIVE] Server already started.


Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013
Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013

Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013

Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013

Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013

Thu Sep 12 21:01:02 UTC 2013
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
[ACTIVE] Server already started.
```

Here's the output from `/var/logs/cron` :

```
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19497]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19498]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19522]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19541]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19549]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:02 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[19565]: starting msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:03 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20166]: finished msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:03 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20182]: finished msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:03 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20243]: finished msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:03 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20288]: finished msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:04 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20310]: finished msm-hourly
Sep 12 21:01:04 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[20315]: finished msm-hourly
```

## Question

I've attempted to replace and rework the script followed by `/etc/init.d/crond reload` and/or `/etc/init.d/crond restart`.

Things restart without errors and the script fires every hour as it should.. just with all the extra lines.

How do I track this down to better understand what's going on and fixing it so that the msm-hourly only runs once per hour?

Comment: Ignoring the cron issue, is restarting the server hourly really the best way?  Are you sure you can't setup something like monit, to verify that the service is functional, and restart as needed with appropriate notifications?

Comment: BTW, what Linux/nix is this?  What version/release of the distro? What cron daemon is being used?

Comment: (Guessing OS is Ubuntu Precise.) Does `/etc/crontab` have multiple `run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`? Does the same happen with any script in `/etc/cron.hourly`? Have you kept backup versions in `/etc/cron.hourly`? Try manually running `run-parts --verbose /etc/cron.hourly`

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/crontab` to make sure the line for `cron.hourly` is similar to the one below (paying particular attention that only the minutes field has a number and the rest are asterisks) and appears only once.

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

Also, make sure your script (or /etc/cron.hourly) is not entered in any other crontabs, including a user's (or root's) and that multiple copies (backups) don't appear in `/etc/cron.hourly`.

Note that the last line in your script can be simplified to:

```
{ echo && /bin/date && /etc/init.d/msm start; } >> $LOGFILE
```

Please also see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).